# What is the correct way, using THREE.js methods to calculate the yaw of the camera?

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js, quaternions

How can I calculate a 2d (aerial-view) representation of an object's rotation (yaw) in my 3d scene using built-in THREE.js methods?

I have this working correctly using the solution from [How to derive "standard" rotations from three.js when using quaternions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167962/how-to-derive-standard-rotations-from-three-js-when-using-quaternions) (same as http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToEuler/); but I would prefer to use built-in methods if available.

Answer (score 3):

To orient the camera using natural yaw (heading), pitch, and roll, set:

```
camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ'. // the default is `XYZ`
```

Now you can set the cameras's orientation like so:

```
camera.rotation.set( pitch_radians, yaw_radians, roll_radians );
```

Consequently, `camera.rotation.y` would be the yaw (heading) in radians.

This method applies equally-well to any three.js `Object3D`.

For more information about an object's rotation in three.js see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517937/three-js-camera-tilt-up-or-down-and-keep-horizon-level/17518092#17518092).

three.js r.69

Comment: the resulting difference from this and the `quatToEuler` function in my linked question seems to be that the `quatToEuler` function considers singularity at the north / south poles. It provides a consistent range between 0 - 2π, useful for an aerial-view map. Thank you for your explanation, it helps me further understand Euler; but is there something in Three.js that is a replica of the behavior from `quatToEuler`?

Comment: (1) Euler angles are not unique, so continuity will always be an issue. Maybe [ -pi, pi ] range will work better... (2) You could use `camera.getWorldDirection( result )`, and then compute the yaw yourself from `result.x` and `result.z`. Based on your continuity requirement, I think that is best approach in your case.

Comment: Also, to answer your last question, there is `Euler.setFromQuaternion( q )` and `Quaternion.setFromEuler( rotation )`. But in three.js, `myobject.quaternion` and `myobject.rotation` self-synchronize.