# Quaterion-rotate bone untill it alignes with a Vector3, three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to rotate a bone so it is aligned with a Vector3 (directionToTarget), I have:

```js
const directionToTarget = new THREE.Vector3(random, random, random); //pseudocode randoms
directionToTarget.normalize();

var Hand2worldQ = new THREE.Quaternion();
this._anchor['LeftHandIndex1'].getWorldQuaternion(Hand2worldQ); // gets Lefthand bone quaternion

this._mesh.skeleton.bones[ 0 ].quaternion.set( SomeFunctionThatMakesVecintoQuarternion(directionToTarget ); 
// this._mesh.skeleton.bones inherits Hand2worldQ/LeftHand rotation
```

SomeFunctionThatMakesVec3intoQuarternion(directionToTarget ) is what i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object3D` starts by looking down the `0, 0, 1` axis. You can [use the `Object3D.lookAt()` method](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt) to make this object point towards your target vector. Then you can extract that rotation and use it for whatever else you need:

```
// Initialize an abstract object looking towards 0, 0, 1
const object3D = new THREE.Object3D();

// Rotate it so it looks towards the target xyz coordinates
object3D.lookAt(randomX, randomY, randomZ);

// This will now have the final rotation
const myQuaternion = object3D.quaternion;
console.log(myQuaternion);
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14168533/1461008.

Comment: @WestLangley Ugh, I always confuse -z for cameras vs +z for Objects. I’ve got to put it on a post-it by my screen. Fixed.